# Is it possible for an OS timer callback to be invoked after global static object destruction?

Tags: c++, linux, timer

I'm rephrasing this question more simply, and with a simpler MCVE after a prior version didn't gain much traction.

I had formed the impression that after `main()` ends, all that happens is global object destruction, then static object destruction, in that order.

I'd never considered the possibility of implications of other "stuff" happening during this period between end of `main()` and end of the process. But I've recently been working with Linux timers, and *experimentally*, it appears that timers' callbacks can be invoked during this "late phase" of a process, after `main()` exits and even after static global objects have been destroyed.

**Question:** Is that assessment correct? Can a timer callback be invoked after static global objects have been destroyed?

I'd never given much thought to what happens this "late" in a process' lifetime. I suppose I'd naively assumed "something" "prevented" "stuff happening" after `main()` exited.

**Question:** My timer callback uses a static global object -- the intent being that the object would "always" be around, regardless of when the callback was invoked. But if timer callbacks can be invoked after static global objects have been destroyed, then that strategy isn't safe. Is there a well-known/correct way to handle this: i.e. prevent timer callbacks from ever accessing invalid objects/memory?

The code below creates "many" timers set to expire 2 seconds in the future, whose callback references a static global object. `main()` exits right around the middle of when timer callbacks are being invoked. `cout`s show that the static global object is destroyed while timer callbacks are still being invoked.

```
// main.cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <cerrno>
#include <csignal>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <mutex>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;
static int tmp = ((srand ( time( NULL ) )), 0);

class Foo { // Encapsulates a random-sized, random-content string.
public:
  Foo() {
    uint32_t size = (rand() % 24) + 1;
    std::generate_n( std::back_inserter( s_ ), size, randChar );
  }

  void operator=( const Foo& other ) { s_ = other.s_; }

  std::string s_;

private:
  static char randChar() { return ('a' + rand() % 26); }
};

class GlobalObj { // Encapsulates a map<timer_t, Foo>.
public:
  ~GlobalObj() { std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }

  Foo* getFoo( const timer_t& timer ) {
    Foo* ret = NULL;
    {
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l( mutex_ );
      std::map<timer_t, Foo*>::iterator i = map_.find( timer );

      if ( map_.end() != i ) {
        ret = i->second;
        map_.erase( i );
      }
    }

    return ret;
  }

  void setFoo( const timer_t& timer, Foo* foo ) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l( mutex_ );
    map_[timer] = foo;
  }

private:
  std::mutex mutex_;
  std::map<timer_t, Foo*> map_;
};

static GlobalObj global_obj; // static global GlobalObj instance.

void osTimerCallback( union sigval sv ) { // The timer callback
  timer_t* timer = (timer_t*)(sv.sival_ptr);

  if ( timer ) {
    Foo* foo = global_obj.getFoo(*timer);

    if ( foo ) {
      cout << "timer[" << *timer << "]: " << foo->s_ << endl;
      delete foo;
    }
    delete timer;
  }
}

bool createTimer( const struct timespec& when ) { // Creates an armed timer.
  timer_t* timer = new timer_t;
  struct sigevent se;
  static clockid_t clock_id =
#ifdef CLOCK_MONOTONIC
    CLOCK_MONOTONIC;
#else
    CLOCK_REALTIME;
#endif

  memset( &se, 0, sizeof se );
  se.sigev_notify = SIGEV_THREAD;
  se.sigev_value.sival_ptr = timer;
  se.sigev_notify_function = osTimerCallback;

  if ( timer_create( clock_id, &se, timer ) ) {
    cerr << "timer_create() err " << errno << " " << strerror( errno ) << endl;
    return false;
  }

  {
    struct itimerspec its;

    memset( &its, 0, sizeof its );
    its.it_value.tv_sec = when.tv_sec;
    its.it_value.tv_nsec = when.tv_nsec;

    if ( timer_settime( *timer, 0, &its, NULL ) ) {
      cerr << "timer_settime err " << errno << " " << strerror( errno ) << endl;
      return false;
    }

    global_obj.setFoo( *timer, new Foo );
  }

  return true;
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) { // Creates many armed timers, then exits
  static const struct timespec when = { 2, 0 };
  for ( uint32_t i = 0; i < 100; ++i ) {
    createTimer( when );
  }
  usleep( 2000010 );
  return 0;
}
```

Example error:

```
$ g++ --version && g++ -g ./main.cpp -lrt && ./a.out
g++ (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

timer[timer[~GlobalObj0x55b34c17bd700x55b34c17be60
]: gx
*** Error in `./a.out': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0xtimer[0x55b34c17bf50]: wsngolhdjvhx
]: npscgelwujjfp
Aborted
```

Note that the error mentions "double free"; the code above has two `delete` statements: removing them does not seem to impact reproducibility of the problem. I believe the error message is a red herring, due to accessing invalidated memory.

Increasing the `usleep()` in `main()` to sufficiently large so as to allow all timer callback invocations to occur *before* the static global object destruction results in consistently successful execution.

Comment: Why aren't you calling `timer_delete()` when you're done with the timer object?  Then it would not fire.

Comment: @JohnZwinck - that is one reason why the code is contrived: I purposely do not `timer_delete()` in order to force this condition. The motivation behind the question was to understand whether indeed timers may fire after static global objects are destroyed. I previously had a hand-wavey (lack of) understanding that "black magic" prevented "stuff happening" after `main()` exits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no magic preventing a timer to fire after the end of `main`.

The common way to prevent things like this happening in C++ is to create a small resource owning class for each type of resource that needs to be manually released. See [RAII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) and [The rule of three/five/zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

The foundation for such a class could look like this:

```
#include <cerrno>    // errno
#include <cstring>   // std::strerror
#include <stdexcept> // std::runtime_error
#include <string>    // std::string
#include <utility>   // std::exchange

class Timer {
public:
    Timer(clockid_t clockid, sigevent& sev) {
        if(timer_create(clockid, &sev, &timerid))
            throw std::runtime_error(std::string("timer_create: ") +
                                     std::strerror(errno));
    }

    // rule of 5
    Timer(const Timer&) = delete;                       // no copy construction

    Timer(Timer&& rhs) :                                // move construction ok
        timerid(std::exchange(rhs.timerid, nullptr)) {}

    Timer& operator=(const Timer&) = delete;            // no copy assignment

    Timer& operator=(Timer&& rhs) {                     // move assignment ok
        if(this != &rhs) {
            if(timerid) timer_delete(timerid);
            timerid = std::exchange(rhs.timerid, nullptr);
        }
        return *this;
    }

    ~Timer() {
        if(timerid) timer_delete(timerid);
    }

private:
    timer_t timerid;
};
```

You can now store your `Timer`s in a container and they will be properly deleted when the container goes out of scope.

Having this approach whenever one has to deal with one of these `create` / `delete` pairs, that are commonly found in C API:s, usually limits the number of surprises like the one you got.

Also read about the [Static Initialization Order Fiasco](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/siof) to avoid other potential pitfalls.

<sup>Note: This implementation makes use of the fact that `timer_t` is a pointer type on my system and I don't know if that's always the case.</sup>